# nginx Listening But Not Responding on non-80/443 Port

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

`nginx` on Mac OS X is running via `brew` successfully on ports `80` and `443`.

However, I am trying to run on a different port `18000` and `nginx` does not want to respond, despite listening to the port.

```
server {
    listen       18000 ssl;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       https://www.new-server.com/;
        proxy_redirect   https://www.new-server.com https://www.example.com;
}
```

I can see the port is being listening on `netstat -na | grep LISTEN | grep 18000`:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.18000                *.*                    LISTEN
```

`sudo lsof -i :18000` shows the port is being listened on as well by `nginx`:

```
nginx     71351       root   11u  IPv4 0x78e8667283110347      0t0  TCP *:18000 (LISTEN)
nginx     71359     nobody   11u  IPv4 0x78e8667282110647      0t0  TCP *:18000 (LISTEN)
```

Yet the access logs do not show anything when I run `curl -k https://example.com:18000`. Nothing shows up in the error log when I start up `nginx` after setting the config above.

How can I further debug this?

Comment: What does `curl -v -k https://example.com:18000` produce?

Comment: Have you configured DNS or /etc/hosts to resolve example.com to your host?

Comment: @AlexeyTen ah, good point - I was not doing this. `nginx` only handles requests to local server, and my requests were not even hitting `nginx` at all because the DNS was resolving to the normal IP address. For some reason I was thinking `nginx` was handling requests _before_ they were resolved. Good catch.